# Why do my nodes keep failing? Failure to start BridgeControlListener

Tags: corda

So when I run `./build/nodes/runnodes` three terminal windows open up and start the nodes but they don't get far

```
⚠️   ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode! ‍   This is not safe for production deployment.
Advertised P2P messaging addresses      : localhost:10015
RPC connection address                  : localhost:10016
RPC admin connection address            : localhost:10049
[ERROR] 18:55:22+0100 [main] bridging.BridgeControlListener. - Failure to start BridgeControlListener
Shutting down ...
[ERROR] 18:55:48+0100 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: stop can't be called twice
```

What is causing this to fail?

Comment: Could you share your node logs. That could have more relevant infirmation.